# Complex mySQL query, find dupes, order by date and by group

Tags: mysql, sql

I´m trying to figure out how to write my query.

First of all i´m looking for dupes in a table:

```
$query = "SELECT datum, element_skanning.objekt_element 
          FROM element_skanning
          INNER JOIN (SELECT objekt_element
                      FROM   element_skanning
                      GROUP  BY objekt_element
                      HAVING COUNT(id) > 1) dup
                      ON element_skanning.objekt_element = dup.objekt_element;                                
          ";

while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
     echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>".$row['objekt_element']."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$row['datum']."</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
}
```

Results looks like:
[image]

You can see there is alot of dupes.
Now i´d like to ORDER these result.

I´d like them by date.. but also grouped.

"23117-12" has three rows with three  different dates.
I´d like them grouped.. starting with the oldest date and ASC.

So take the date that is oldest, and list the other result from that group.
 Then you take the date from next dupe, list this group of dupes. and so on..

Do i need to explain my self better?

How is this possible?

**EDIT**

Expected output would be:
[image]

Comment: share your expected output?

Comment: @KMS Did it make more sense?

Comment: I have a solution that first get all the dupes. Then make a loop and fetch all dupes and list them dupe by dupe.. it is working.. but it is not fast ;)

Comment: Next time please post data as text, not images. This makes it easier for us to use the data in our databases and try our queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply select the minimum `datum` per `objekt_element` along in order to use it for sorting:

```
SELECT es.datum, es.objekt_element 
FROM element_skanning es
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT objekt_element, MIN(datum) AS min_datum
  FROM element_skanning
  GROUP BY objekt_element
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) dup ON es.objekt_element = dup.objekt_element
ORDER BY dup.min_datum, es.objekt_element, es.datum;
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. And i will take notice about your comment!